# How to mock a class which calls an invokation block?

Tags: objective-c, tdd, fmdb, ocmock, invocation

I'm digging myself into TDD and startet using SenTestingKit along with [OCMock](http://ocmock.org). I'm using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) as a wrapper for my SQLite Database.

I can't get my head around how to mock the `DatabaseQueue` class, so it correctly invokes the invocation block with an `FMDatabase` object.

Any ideas?

#### CustomerFactory.h

```
@interface CustomerFactory

// DatabaseQueue inherits from FMDatabaseQueue
@property (nonatomic, retain) DatabaseQueue *queue;

- (id)initWithDatabaseQueue:(DatabaseQueue *)queue;

@end
```

#### CustomerFactory.m

```
@implement CustomerFactory

- (id)initWithDatabaseQueue:(DatabaseQueue *)queue
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        [self setQueue:queue];
    }
}

- (NSArray *)customersByCategory:(NSUInteger)categoryId
{
    __block NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self.queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db)
    {
        FMResultSet *result = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM customers WHERE category_id = ?", categoryId];

        while ([result next])
        {
            Customer *customer = [[Customer alloc] initWithDictionary:[result resultDictionary]];
            [temp addObject:customer;
        }
    }];

    return temp;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing the **CustomerFactory** class, then you should not do it at all. Think about it as testing the interface of our unit, which is a **CustomerFactory** instance. You have the method called *customersByCategory:* and you are only interested in getting the NSArray of your customers object from this call. The fact that you use the **DatabaseQueue** and *FMDatabase* instances inside is the implementation detail which should be transparent to this specific unit test.

Testing the **DatabaseQueue** class is a different story, but it looks like the easiest way to achieve what you want is to use a real instance of the **DatabaseQueue** in your test.

Comment: But this would require a filled Database to test. I managed to get it working but my test is horrible long. I'm thinking of refactoring it, so it's easier to test. Will update my Question tomorrow at work. I want to test as many code without integration tests.

Comment: I think your **DatabaseFactory** class depends on the FMDatabaseQueue too much and testing it as a separate unit wouldn't really make sense unless you have a test database against which you can run this kind of unit test.